Is there an efficient way to find all transactions that change the balance of a given account?
I want to programmatically obtain the list of all changes to the balance of a given account. I can split this task into 4 smaller tasks: accounts can be externally owned or smart contract, and changes can be incoming or outgoing. So, a different approach is needed for each cell of the following table, and filling this table will complete the solution.



transaction direction \ account ownership
externally owned
smart contract




outgoing
outgoing transactions from an externally owned account
outgoing transactions from a smart contract


incoming
incoming transaction to an externally owned account
incoming transactions to a smart contract



Let us walk through this table cell by cell.
outgoing transactions from an externally owned account
This is easy. I can call eth_getBlockTransactionCountByNumber, get the number of transactions in the given block, and then repeatedly call eth_getTransactionByBlockNumberAndIndex that many times with increasing index, looking for transactions with the given address in the from field. I could even do it by hand — I only need to download the block and parse the transactions out of it.
outgoing transactions from a smart contract
This is much more complicated.
To start, I need to find all transactions to the given smart contract address, emulate the contract running the relevant method code, and find all CALL, CALLCODE, CREATE, CREATE2 and SELFDESTRUCT opcodes executed — these are the opcodes that can be used to transfer ether from the smart contract being run. Soon EXTCALL and EOFCREATE may need to be added to this list, as per EIP-7069 and EIP-7620 respectively.
But this is not all. I also need to emulate all other smart contracts that have been run in the given block, and see if they called the given smart contract, and then emulate it as above. But any of these smart contracts may have also called other smart contracts that then called the given smart contract, and so on. Long story short, I need to emulate all the computations performed by all smart contracts in the given block.
This is what I call «inefficient» for the purpose of this question.
An optimization is to only emulate contracts that can possibly be aware of the given address, by looking at the transaction data. But this is not reliable: nothing stops anyone from deploying a smart contract that accepts an arbitrarily encrypted address, decrypts it and transfers ether to it — our optimized algorithm will not detect this.
So far as I can tell, there is no method in the JSON-RPC API that can help me.
incoming transaction to an externally owned account
This seems to also be inefficient. Any smart contract could have sent some ether to the given address. I must emulate everything. The reasoning above applies.
incoming transactions to a smart contract
Also inefficient, for the same reason as above.
conclusion
As far as I can tell, the design of the Ethereum infrastructure only provides an efficient way to cover one cell of our table — outgoing transactions from an externally owned account. All three other cells need full emulation of the given block.



transaction direction \ account ownership
externally owned
smart contract




outgoing
outgoing transactions from an externally owned account —  efficient
outgoing transactions from a smart contract —  inefficient


incoming
incoming transaction to an externally owned account —  inefficient
incoming transactions to a smart contract —  inefficient




Is this true?
Is this a fundamental problem? That is, is this a problem inherent to the design of the Ethereum blockchain data structure, or is this simply something no one bothered to implement?

notes

I am aware that some smart contracts will be nice and log something by emitting an event whenever they handle ether. But, so far as I can tell, this is not enforced and not standardized in any way, so I can only reliably use event logs if I am interested in transactions from a specific class of smart contracts that I know will log what I need to know.

I am also aware of services like https://etherscan.io that collect and integrate information from the blockchain with the eye to offer such a service. I wish to double check it myself.


